# Is it possible to insert variable inside single quote string?

Tags: php

```
<?php $header_string = '<a href="get_bloginfo('url')">Holiday</a>'; ?>
```

How do I insert `get_bloginfo('url')` correctly inside the single quoted string above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $header_string = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '">Holiday</a>'; ?>
```

Note the use of the dots (`.`), which are used for [concatenating strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation

```
<?php $header_string = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'">Holiday</a>'; ?>
```